# WebView Problem in Android

Tags: android, android-webview

Main.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/rlayout1">
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Back"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:id="@+id/mBtnBackMore" />
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="More" android:id="@+id/txtviewfbdisplaytitle" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_below="@+id/rlayout1"
        android:id="@+id/rlayout2">
        <WebView android:id="@+id/mWebViewMore" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Main_Activity.Java:-

```
public class Main_Activity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
          @Override
          public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
              view.loadUrl(url);
              System.out.println("URL is:- " +url);
              return true;
          }
    }

    Button btnBack;
    WebView webview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.more);
        webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.mWebView);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        openURL();
        btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mBtnBack);
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

     /** Opens the URL in a browser */
    private void openURL() {
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        webview.requestFocus();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        finish();
    }  
}
```

I am Using Above Code for Display Web View & Load http://www.google.com URL in Web View but Problem is The WebView is Display Google.com in Emulator not in Actual Device.

Please Help Me.

Comment: please check internet connectivity of your phone device

Comment: In Actual device, whats happening ?

Comment: Internet Connectivity is Very Good and the http://www.google.com is open in Device Browser.

Comment: please provide your androidmenifest.Try to open google.com on Device browser it loads or not

Comment: Hey, try doing this trick..worked for me...make WebView's hight n width in XML to WRAP_CONTENT..and check that...tell me what happend?

Comment: In Actual Device "Web Page Not Available" is displayed.

Comment: I would thought this leads to recursion. You says you are overriding URL loading and execute same request, then you says you are overriding URL loading .... Try remove `view.loadUrl(url);` and return `false` instead.

Comment: I Removed View.loadurl(url) & set return false but this is also not working.

Comment: @DipakKeshariya try this remove return true; and put return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url); instead

Comment: have you added permissions to your manifest??